# pattern matching using regular expression in F#

Tags: regex, f#

How to find "From :  Sent : Received:  " pattern from any given string. IF given pattern is present in string then take out substring up to first pattern and ignore rest string. Is there is any regular expression for achieving same ? 
note: there may be text present between From : Sent : and received:.

Comment: And at least an attempt

Comment: Must it be a regular expression? How about parsing the string?

Comment: hi Foggy
i want to parse following string :


"Sent:
From:
hi user
 please parse following string

thanks and regards,
user2.
.......................................
From: some text
Sent : some text
To:  some text
Subject : some text

hi user
 please parse following string
....................
From: some text
Sent : some text
To:  some text
Subject : some text
............some text "



output  should be :
"hi user
please parse following string

thanks and regards,
user2"

Comment: Hi Mark .. I thought regular expression will solve this problem. Is their any other way to the do same ?

Comment: HI Foggy .. not yet solved

Answer (score 5):

Using a [*partial active pattern*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) this could look like

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let (|UpToFromSentReceived|_|) candidate =
    let pattern = Regex("(.*?)From:.*Sent:.*Received:")
    let matches = pattern.Match candidate
    if matches.Success then matches.Groups.[1].Value.Trim() |> Some else None
```

which could then be used

```
let test = function
    | UpToFromSentReceived prefix -> printfn "%s" prefix
    | s -> printfn "No match for '%s'" s

// Arbitrary prefix
test "Arbitrary prefix From: Sent: Received:"

// No match for 'Arbitrary prefix From: Sent: sorry ;-P'
test "Arbitrary prefix From: Sent: sorry ;-P"

// Foo Bar
test "Foo Bar From: arbitrary Sent: interspersed Received: text"

// First Foo Bar
test "First Foo Bar From: arbitrary Sent: interspersed Received: text Second Foo Bar From: arbitrary Sent: interspersed Received: text"
```

Depending on your requirements you may want to leave out the `.Trim()`

Comment: @RHC Nice answer, thanx. Now know how to use it.

Comment: Nice answer, Thanx. But when I tried to parse "Arbitrary prefix From:   Received: From: Sent: Received: From: Sent: Received: From: Sent: Received:"  using above logic It gives output as "Arbitrary prefix". But Output should be "Arbitrary prefix From:   Received:"